# How to use asterisk in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

How to set label in black color and asterisk (*) in red color.

```
<FormLabel>{I18n.strings("account.nickname")}*</FormLabel>
```

By default label getting black, i need asterisk in red..

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FormLabel>{I18n.strings("account.nickname")}<Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>*</Text></FormLabel>
```

Comment: Thanks man <3 It's working after i import text in 'react-native-elements' you deserve it @Tareq El-Masri

Comment: Or simply `import { Text } from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 2):

I found this as simple

```
<Text style={styles.titleContainer}>Head category<Text style={{color:'red', justifyContent:'center'}}>*</=Text> </Text>
```